# java.net.MalformedURLException When passing AsyncTask String

Tags: android, android-asynctask, malformedurlexception

I am getting the following error `java.net.MalformedURLException` in Logcat when trying to execute my String that contains my URL with Asynctask. I know the string contains the correct URL because I am using it to load an image into an ImageView via Picasso Library(See below).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Async Task class:

```
public class SetWallpaperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String image_url;
URL ImageUrl;
String myFileUrl1;
Bitmap bmImg = null;

public SetWallpaperAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStream is = null;

    try {

        ImageUrl = new URL(args[0]);
        // myFileUrl1 = args[0];

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ImageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (bmImg == null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Image still loading...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

    else {

        WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        try {
            wpm.setBitmap(bmImg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (pDialog != null) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper Successfully Set!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
}
```

What is says it Logcat once called:

```
     04-15 13:42:57.764: W/System.err(5753): java.net.MalformedURLException
04-15 13:42:57.764: W/System.err(5753):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:154)
04-15 13:42:57.764: W/System.err(5753):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
04-15 13:42:57.768: W/System.err(5753):     at com.jaypps.SetWallpaperAsync.doInBackground(SetWallpaperAsync.java:58)
04-15 13:42:57.772: W/System.err(5753):     at com.jaypps.SetWallpaperAsync.doInBackground(SetWallpaperAsync.java:1)
04-15 13:42:57.772: W/System.err(5753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-15 13:42:57.772: W/System.err(5753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-15 13:42:57.772: W/System.err(5753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-15 13:42:57.776: W/System.err(5753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-15 13:42:57.776: W/System.err(5753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-15 13:42:57.776: W/System.err(5753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-15 13:42:57.776: W/System.err(5753):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-15 13:42:57.792: W/EGL_emulation(5753): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Also, here is how I am calling Async Task, Also, I know that the String I am passing it to set the wallpaper contains the correct URL because I am also passing the same String to load that image into an ImageView using the Picasso Library:

```
public class ImageViewer extends SherlockFragment {

private String ImageURL;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageviewpager, container, false);

    ImageView IMGView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(getArguments().getString(ImageURL))
            .into(IMGView);

    IMGView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            new SetWallpaperAsync(getActivity()).execute(ImageURL);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

 }
```

Comment: where is this initialized `ImageURL`??

Comment: How would I initialize it?, it works when passing it to Picasso so it can be downloaded into my ImageView(See clause at bottom), that's why I am confused because it has to contain a URL for it to load and it does.

Comment: read java initialization of variables in the java docs. I don't see a url `private String ImageURL;` `ImageURL = "my url`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are definitively not using an URL. Use the debugger to check what is the actual content of that string. You are also not initializing the url variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `ImageUrl` is a valid http url
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MalformedURLException.html

Comment: Well, it has to be because I am passing it as a URL to Picasso so it can load the image into my ImageView if you look at the bottom clause of code, it works perfectly.

Comment: print value of `args[0]` in logcat in `doInBackground` and see is it well formed http url.